# Match list to rows of matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

"a" is a list and "b" is a matrix.

```
a<-list(matrix(c(0,2,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2),4), 
        matrix(c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),3),
        matrix(c(0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,1,0,1,1,0),5))
b<-matrix(c(2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1),6) 

> a
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    2
[4,]    1    0    0    2

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1
[5,]    2    0    2    0

> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    1    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    2
[5,]    1    2    1    1
[6,]    2    1    2    1
```

There are 3 objects in list "a". I want to test whether all the **non-zero** elements in each object in the list "a" match with the corresponding position of the same row in matrix "b". If matched, output the matched row number of b.

For example, the second object is

```
[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
```

We can see the non-zero number in the 1st row is 1, and it locates in the third place of the row, it can match the 1-5 rows of matrix "b", the non-zero number in the 2nd row is 1, and it locates in the first place of this row, it can match the 3-5 rows of matrix "b", the non-zero number in the 3rd row is 1, and it locates in the second place of this row, it can match the 3-4 rows of matrix "b". so only the 3rd or 4th row of Matrix "b" can match all the rows in this object, so the output result is "3 4".

My attempting code is as follows:

```
temp<-Map(function(y) t(y), Map(function(a) 
           apply(a,1,function(x){
                 apply(b,1, function(y) identical(x[x!=0],y[x!=0]))}),a))
lapply(temp, function(a) which(apply(a,2,prod)==1))
```

The result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

It is right. but I wonder whether there is more quick code to handle this question?

Comment: Actually element [3,4] doesn't match...

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Why? It is matched. All the non-zero elements in the first object of "a" match the corresponding position of the second row of matrix "b", all the non-zero elements in 2nd object of "a" match the corresponding position of the 5th row of matrix "b", and all the non-zero elements in third object of "a" match the corresponding position of the 6th row of matrix "b".

Comment: What are the dimensions of your actual data?

Comment: @alexis_laz  "a" has 300 objects(each object is a matrix (round 20X5)), "b" is a 15-row matrix.

Comment: What's supposed to happen if you have two non-zero numbers in the same column, like in `a[[1]]`?

Comment: @alistaire  if it has two or more DIFFERENT non-zero numbers in the same column, it means the object (eg. a[[1]]) doesn't match any of the rows in matrix "b", so the expected result is "integer(0)".

Comment: `fun <- function(x){
  id <- which(x != 0, arr.ind=T)
  which(apply(b[,id[,'col']], 1, identical, x[id]))
} ; lapply(a, fun)`

Comment: I have no idea how the result of `[[2]]` is `3, 4`. The non-zero elements are `c(1,1,1,0)`, which do not match to any of the rows of `b`

Comment: @Chris The non-zero elements in [[2]] is c(1,1,1,  ),so it doesn't matter what  is the number on the fourth place, since the 3rd and 4th row of "b" can match c(1,1,1,  ), so the answer is "3  4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a few columns and trying to take advantage of columns with > 1 unique values or no non-zero values to reduce computations:

```
ff = function(a, b)
{
    i = seq_len(nrow(b))  #starting candidate matches
    for(j in seq_len(ncol(a))) {
        aj = a[, j]
        nzaj = aj[aj != 0L]
        if(!length(nzaj)) next  #if all(a[, j] == 0) save some operations
        if(sum(tabulate(nzaj) > 0L) > 1L) return(integer())  #if no unique values in a column break looping 
        i = i[b[i, j] == nzaj[[1L]]]  #update candidate matches
    }

    return(i)
}
lapply(a, function(x) ff(x, b))
#[[1]]
#integer(0)
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 6
```

With data of your actual size:

```
set.seed(911)
a2 = replicate(300L, matrix(sample(0:3, 20 * 5, TRUE, c(0.97, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01)), 20, 5), simplify = FALSE)
b2 = matrix(sample(1:3, 15 * 5, TRUE), 15, 5)
identical(OP(a2, b2), lapply(a2, function(x) ff(x, b2)))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(OP(a2, b2), lapply(a2, function(x) ff(x, b2)), times = 50)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
#                        OP(a2, b2) 686.961815 730.840732 760.029859 753.790094 785.310056 863.04577    50   b
# lapply(a2, function(x) ff(x, b2))   8.110542   8.450888   9.381802   8.949924   9.872826  15.51568    50  a
```

`OP` is:

```
OP = function (a, b) 
{
    temp = Map(function(y) t(y), Map(function(a) apply(a, 1, 
        function(x) {
            apply(b, 1, function(y) identical(x[x != 0], y[x != 
                0]))
        }), a))
    lapply(temp, function(x) which(apply(x, 2, prod) == 1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your explanations of what you want and what your possible matrices look like are really not clear. From what I can deduce, you want to match the row number in `b` that matches the unique non-zero number in each column of a matrix in `a`. If so, here's a simpler option:

```
lapply(a, function(x){    # loop across the matrices in a
    x[x == 0] <- NA       # replace 0s with NA
    which(apply(b, 1, function(y){            # loop across the rows of b, trying to match
        all(y == colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE))   # the rows of b with the colmeans of x
    }))
})
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6
```

Comment: Hi, @alistaire, if elements in one column are all 0 in the object of list "a", then your answer will go wrong, thank you. Look at such situation in the second object of "a"

Comment: for example, every row in a[[2]] can match with the 3rd and 4th row in matrix "b", because all the non-zero elements can match the corresponding position(column) in the 3rd or 4th row of "b". However, with your code, the result turns out to be "integer(0)", since you consider all the column contains non-zero elements.

Comment: You need to fully lay out the logic you need the code to follow. Updating the example is good, but you still haven't explained how it's supposed to evaluate to the desired result, leaving readers to guess.

Comment: Yes, it is a little difficult to express, I think what you deduced is right.