# Change some values of matrix to form a new matrix

Tags: r, matrix

"a" is a matrix.

```
a<-matrix(1:20,5)
```

I want to change the first column of "a" into 1 to form a new matrix "b", and I also need to keep "a" as it was.

Now I can only reach this goal by following code:

```
 b<-a
 b[,1]=1
```

How can I solve this problem with only one-sentence code?

Comment: May I ask why you care? Aesthetics, curiosity, ... ?  (@Julius's solution is nice but actually more characters than `b <- a; b[,1] <- 1` ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Maybe in order to save time and more simple

Comment: @BenBolker if you think this question is too native and silly, could you help me with a little complicated one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459958/match-list-to-rows-of-matrix-in-r         Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replace(a, col(a) == 1, 1)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16
# [2,]    1    7   12   17
# [3,]    1    8   13   18
# [4,]    1    9   14   19
# [5,]    1   10   15   20
```

and, in this case, also `cbind(1, a[, -1])`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both look nice. @Julius